# Calling a class from different file cmake

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I am writing a library for example:
FooBar/foobar.cpp
FooBar/foobar.h
FooBar/bar.cpp
FOoBar/bar.h

and foobar.h inlcudes "bar.h"

I want to use cmakefiles to build this library.

What would an example file look like

Note that this doesnt have any "main" function so there are no executable I want to create. I just want to build a library which I can include in different project.

I tried different permutations and combinations

but in every attempt i throws an error in FooBar where I am trying to call a method from bar.cpp?
 THanks

Comment: So `g++ -c FooBar.cpp` compiles directly from the command line, but not if you use cmake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
project(FooBar)
add_library(FooBar FooBar/foobar.cpp FooBar/foobar.h FooBar/bar.cpp FooBar/bar.h)
# this will create a library called FooBar that will have the code from foobar.cpp and bar.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

After 10 seconds of googling, I found [this helpful site.](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/cpp/gcc/create_lib.html)

Your makefile should look like this:

```
obj/bar.o : FooBar/bar.cpp FooBar/bar.h
    g++ -c FooBar/bar.cpp -o obj/bar.o

libbar.a : obj/bar.o
    ar rcs libbar.a obj/bar.o
```

Then you can just link libbar.a in to your program

Comment: This will be at same level dir level as that of the bar.cpp bar.h foobar.cpp and foobar.h or is this the cmakefile at FooBar level.?

Comment: I was just using names according to the names you provided. I rarely write makefiles, but I'm pretty sure paths are based on the location of the makefile